# Can photos in messages be shared to Apple mail

Tags: macos, ios, mail.app, photos, messages

I often receive photos in Messages that I would like to forward to others via eamil. Currently I am using a copy/paste method but frequently I get multiple copies of the photo pasted.

**Any suggestions on how I can message photos by sharing/exporting directly to Apple Mail from the Messages app?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an easier way to do this. Since it's not clear whether you're on a Mac or iPhone/iPad, I'll provide steps for doing this on both.

**From a Mac:**

1. Within your message (i.e. in the Messages app) double-click on the photo
2. The photo will open in a separate window
3. Click on the *Share* icon at top right of the window
4. Select the Mail option from the menu
5. This will now open a brand new email window with the photo already attached

**From an iPhone/iPad**

1. Within your message (i.e. in the Messages app) tap on the photo
2. The photo will enlarge
3. Click on the *Share* icon at bottom left of screen
4. Select the Mail option from the menu
5. This will now open a brand new email window with the photo already attached

Comment: Sorry, was unclear that I would like  to share from iPhone Message. I can do as you suggested on the iMac Message, but not from the iOS version.

Comment: Ah, ok, I've updated my answer and edited your question. Let me know if you still have any questions.